# How to stop google.com from showing recent search drop-down list?

Tags: google-search, google-search-history

When I place my cursor in the search box at google.com, it displays a drop-down list of recent searches.

I want to disable this behavior because the recent search suggestions  are irrelevant to me.

I know that they won't appear after I clear my history and prevent Google from saving my activity, but it also turns off customized searches and services.

Is there a way to simply disable the drop-down list?

Answer (score 0):

You can switch off instant search via your settings http://www.google.com/preferences. It is not possible to disable the autocomplete.